# Offsite Backup for SQL Server .bak files (only 5 GB)

Tags: backup

I'm looking into possible ideas for off site backup for my SQL Server database backups.
I have a ton of space a dream host. I could create a SFTP account and automatically SFTP new backups to that site. And store them in a folder the the public cannot access.

However I was also looking a Mozy and carbonite.
I could configure them to watch my backup source folder and they would automatically backup the files every 2 hours.
I called Mozy and they said it would be about $9.95 per month if I had 5gb of data.

What does everyone one recommend?
Keeping in mind that I'm a just a start-up and I'm not buying another server for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with the mozy or carbonite backups.  If they'll watch the folder and sync it automatically whenever you make a change for $10, you'll be in far better shape than buying $5/month shared hosting then needing to worry about scripts, schedules, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, Dreamhost doesn't permit storage in their hosting accounts such that you're mentioning here.  Have a look at their [**policy on what "unlimited" means**](http://www.dreamhost.com/unlimited.html), under the heading **What's not allowed in "Unlimited"?**.

I don't have any experience with Mozy (or any others for that matter), but $10 / month for storage and automation doesn't seem too bad of a deal to me...

Comment: So with dreamhost 50GB can be used for backups, that's more than enough for me.

Comment: @aron - That strikes me as 50GB for your backup of data *on that server*, not from another server.

Comment: As a follow on from my last comment, they would also be quite within their rights to terminate your account for breach of the TOS. Not something you want with your critical backup files.

Comment: @aron: yeah, what @Ben said.  If you're thinking of relying on Dreamhost as your backup then I'd definitely give them a call and double check that what you're doing is within their TOS.  I'm not a betting man, but I'd wager it isn't.

Comment: under the section you referenced: `Basically, sites whose essential purpose is to use disk or bandwidth`. @aron - by all means call them and check, but don't expect them to say it's OK.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/).  It's darn close to free for the amount of data you're talking about.

You might have to write a short wrapper to get the data there, but that should be pretty simple.

Oh, and you should encrypt all off-site backups.